# QT C++ - QNetworkAccessManager help needed! Class problem

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork

I'm trying to download a page from a server to my QT program, but I've been searching ways to do it and they don't really work a lot. I'm not an expert in QT/C++, so be kind :)

Well.. So far I come with this code:

**[OLD CODE] - Check the updated code bellow!**

**http.cpp**

```
#include "http.h"

http::http(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

    qDebug() << "HTTP ST";

    http1 = new QHttp(this);
    connect(http1, SIGNAL(done(bool)), this, SLOT(httpdown())); // Correction 1.
    http1->setHost("localhost");
    http1->get("/test.php");

    qDebug() << "HTTP END";


}

void http::httpdown()
{

    qDebug() << "completed!";
    qDebug() << http1->readAll();


}
```

**http.h**

```
#ifndef HTTP_H
#define HTTP_H

#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QHttp>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

class http : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit http(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void httpdown();

private:
    QHttp *http1;

};

#endif // HTTP_H
```

Well the problem is that httpdown() is never called, and I've tried anything I know :( Probably I'm not doing this correctly.

Help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

---

### QUESTION UPDATE

I've ear the suggestion of **alexisdm** and to check QNetworkAccessManager. So here it is new code working on the main() correctly.

When I run it from another class I never get the signal.

**[NEW CODE]**

**http2.cpp**

```
#include "http2.h"

http2::http2(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(m_manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(httpdown(QNetworkReply*)));

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://localhost/test.php"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyOwnBrowser 1.0");

    m_manager->get(request);
}

void http2::httpdown(QNetworkReply* result)
{

       QByteArray data= result->readAll();
       QString str(data);

       qDebug() <<  str;

}
```

**http2.h**

```
#ifndef HTTP2_H
#define HTTP2_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class http2 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit http2(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void httpdown(QNetworkReply* result);
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_manager;

};

#endif // HTTP2_H
```

Now if I call it directly under main.cpp like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "tcpserver.h"
#include "http2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    http2 h; // --> Working!!

    tcpserver mServer;

    return a.exec();
}
```

It works fine. However if I call it inside the tcpserver class like this:

**tcpserver.cpp**

```
#include "tcpserver.h"
#include "protocol.h"
#include "http2.h"

QTextStream in(stdin);

tcpserver::tcpserver(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);

    [ ... Other Server Stuff ... ]

    // http2 h; // --> OLD CODE - Not Working :(

    http2 *h = new http2(this); // **--> NEW CODE working provided by alexisdm**

}
```

The signal never happens... What's wrong? I'm new here! :P

Anyway, **alexisdm said**: "Maybe the http object gets destroyed before the signal can be emitted (if it was allocated on the stack for example)" - **Solution accepted, code bellow corrected** Read this: [QT C++ - QNetworkAccessManager help needed! Class problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191940/qt-c-qnetworkaccessmanager-help-needed-class-problem/7194834#7194834) (link to answer)

What should I do to avoid that?

Thanks! ;)

Comment: You should post your main() function too, since there doesn't seem to be any problem with that part of the code (except that `QHttp` is deprecated, and you should have used `QNetworkAccessManager` instead).

Comment: @alexisdm as I told to MrLunchtime I'm not directly running this under main(). I'll check QNetworkAccessManager. Thanks.

Comment: @alexisdm - Thanks! Please check the post above, I might missed something but the new code using QNetworkAccessManager is working. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `http` or `http2` object is destroyed at the end of the constructor, because it is allocated locally.

You should at least allocate it dynamically:

```
http2 *h = new http2(this);
```

If you want to reuse it, you can also declare it as a member of `tcpserver`, instead of using a local variable. If not, you should destroy it somehow when it is not needed anymore.

---

**Edit**

- If the destruction is done within the slot and/or in response to a signal from `h`, you should use `QObject::deleteLater` rather than an immediate delete, because the object might still be referenced somewhere at the time the signal is emitted. 
  So either `deleteLater();` in `httpdown()` or `h->deleteLater();` in a `tcpserver` slot.
- To know if you have an answer or an error you could use [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177433/how-can-i-read-the-data-sent-from-the-server-in-a-variable-of-type-qnetworkreply/7178307#7178307) and forward either the data or the error to your `tcpserver` class with custom signal(s) and slot(s).

Comment: It works fine, thanks. Whats is the best way to destroy it on the end? Thanks.

Comment: if I change httpdown() to a QByteArray how should I get the answer back to the tcpserver class when it's called big the signal? and how can I know when I've got a answer? :S

Comment: hi thanks, I was using that method to get the data, but how can I return it to the tcpserver class? like wait for the data get back in the tcpclass before do other things...?

Comment: Put the "other things" in a slot connected to a signal that you'll emit in `httpdown()`.

Comment: Well... I can't put the other things in a slot... this is like a checkpoint were the program need to check. I need to wait on that moment (on the tcpserver class) until there's a answer from the http and then get it and process it. I've tried to add a bool on the http2 so it would only continue after the data was returned but it doesn't work.

Comment: hi, check the main thread, It's updated with this question ;) thanks.

Comment: I think you should start a new question for your sub question, and maybe revert the question to the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
SIGNAL(bool)
```

really doesn't look right; did you mean

```
SIGNAL(done(bool))
```

?

In debug mode, there should be some debug output saying that it could not connect the signals.

Comment: yes, sorry I was cleaning the code while posting here... but it doesn't work httpdown() is never called.

Comment: Have you started up (exec()'d) a QApplication/ QCoreApplication?

Edit: I've made it into a proper application here, and httpDown() gets called OK.

Comment: Well, here's what I have, anyway: I've modified it to grab /index.html from www.google.com :

http://bit.ly/qKeJ1q

(and also to report errors, if they occur).

Comment: It works fine I discovered now that the problem is that I'm calling the http from another class in my program. If I call it on main() it works fine. What's the problem with calling it from anther class?

Comment: I can't think of any problem with that.  Is it called while the QCoreApplication is not exec()'ing?

Comment: My program is a TCP socket server and I need to get a value from the http server before start the server but it need to be done inside the  server so I can use the data and call it again later to read some other stuff.

Comment: Maybe the `http` object gets destroyed before the signal can be emitted (if it was allocated on the stack for example).