# Qt - How to get responseText with QNetworkAccessmanager

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

Here is my code:

```
Widget::Widget()
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com")));
}
void Widget::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    //some other code here
}
```

I hope that *reply* will have some method like getrespnsetext() but it not...
Can some one show me an example, all the thing i need is print out the response text (is ther any way like in Javascript Ajax)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7177433/894321

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to use `reply->readAll()` inside the `replyFinished(...)` function to read all the returned text. It returns a `QByteArray`, so you can do wathever you want from there.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation for `QNetworkReply` [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworkreply.html#finished), specifically at the finished signal, it mentions that you can use `readAll()` to get a `QByteArray` of all of the data.  Assuming that you know whether or not such a conversion is valid, `QString` does have a constructor that takes a `QByteArray` as a parameter, as documented [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstring.html#QString-9).