# how to login to the application using JSON data in Qt c++

Tags: c++, json, qt

I am trying to access data from url string https://10.201.58.88:2342/kirk/1.0/h...physicaldrives but it is showing me Host require Authentication 
so I have to login for my app using JSON Url

```
https://10.201.58.88:2342/kirk/1.0/session 
{
"user":
{
"uname": "root",
"kirk_access": "ADMIN",
"hosts":
[
{
      "host_key": "824D103048EB0116A",
       "ip": "10.201.58.88",
       "port": "2342",
        "hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
        "is_local_host": "true",
         "auth_type": "host",
         "uname": "root",
          "config_type": "enterprise",
          "sys_access": "ADMIN"

}
]
},
```

how to get Login and access data from https://10.201.58.88:2342/kirk/1.0/h...physicaldrives

```
Url serviceURL("https://10.201.58.87:2342/kirk/1.0/session");
QNetworkRequest request(serviceURL);


request.setRawHeader("Host","10.201.58.88:2342");
request.setRawHeader("host_key", "824D10304816A");
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", " gzip, deflate");
request.setRawHeader("Referer", "https://10.201.58.87:2342/ui/core/index.html");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", "46");
request.setRawHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

QByteArray usr = "root";
QByteArray pwd = "abc@123";
QByteArray jsonString = "{\"uname\":\"" +usr+"\", \"pwd\":\""+pwd+"\"}";


Q QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QEventLoop loop;
connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
reply = manager.post(request, jsonString);


qDebug() << "post" << reply;
qDebug() << "get" << manager.get(request);
QByteArray response = reply->readAll();

qDebug() << " response" << response;
loop.exec();
```

I have tried this but getting

Starting ....build-layout-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\layout.exe...

post QNetworkReplyHttpImpl(0x2386790)
get QNetworkReplyHttpImpl(0x365a50)
response ""
error "Unknown error"

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't wait for the `POST` request is finished and read the response too early. You need to put `loop.exec();` after `manager.post()` and `manager.get()` calls.

Comment: reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(Url));
    reply->ignoreSslErrors();
    loop.exec();  still getting the same

Comment: Try to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981239/qt-how-to-get-responsetext-with-qnetworkaccessmanager I think you should connect a slot to manager and wait for the NetworkManager to call that slot when it has a response ready.

Comment: I have tried it but getting the same